# GoogleChartToolをオフライン環境で使いたい

Tags: google-api, データの可視化

タイトルの通りですが
GoogleChartは

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

をinclude必要するがあるので、このままではオフライン環境では使用できないと思います。

また、jsファイルのみとってくるのも規約違反とのことでした
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq から引用

> Our terms of service do not allow you to download the google.charts.load or google.visualization code to use offline.

インターネットに接続しないイントラ環境上のWebアプリ(もしくはローカル環境)で
GoogleChartのようなグラフ表示をしたいのですが方法はありますでしょうか？

あるいは代替の方法がありましたらご教示頂きたく思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

グラフを描画する部分にのみ注目すると、有名どころという意味で D3.js は如何でしょうか：https://d3js.org/。

あるいは他にも似たようなオープンソースなフロントエンドでのグラフ描画ライブラリはいくつか知られています：

- plotly.js https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js
- chart.js https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js

Answer (score -2):

出来ないとFAQに記載があります。

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq
Can I use charts offline?